# django deleteview edit performance

Tags: python, django

I'm new in Django,
I'm learning class based view and all works fine, what I'm trying to do is to edit the DeleteView performance, this just delete de object but what im looking is to edit the object instead of delete

```
class borrar(DeleteView):
    model = Usuario
    template_name = "usuario_confirm_delete.html" 
    success_url = '/alta/'
```

I would like to edit but I do not know how to achieve this.

```
Usuario.objects.filter(id=23).update(activo='False')
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UpdateView` to edit objects.